# VBA Hint Text in UserForm TextBox

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

How to add a hint text to a `TextBox` in a `UserForm` that will disappear once a user types anything in?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a `Label` element.

- Type a hint text.
- Set `BackColor`, `Height`, `Left`, `Top`, and `Width` properties to match that of the `TextBox` that will be added later.

**Note:** Setting `BackColor` to `Window Background` (from the drop-down list) will match the common background color of a text box.

- Set `ForeColor` property (a different from `TextBox` text color allows to distinguish the hint text from the entered one).

2. Add a `TextBox` element.

- Set `BackColor`, `Height`, `Left`, `Top`, and `Width` properties.
- Set `BackStyle` property to `fmBackStyleTransparent`.

3. Add the following code to `Sub TextBox_Change`:

```
   If TextBox.Value = "" Then
     TextBox.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
   Else
     TextBox.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
   End If
```

Here is the result:

[image: The result]